# What does initialized with the upper case letters of the alphabet mean?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an assignment that says `Display the English alphabet (A, B, C, D, ...Z) in reverse order, reading the data from a one-dimensional array that is initialized with the upper case letters of the alphabet`

**The problem is I dont understand what is meant** by `initialized with the upper case letters of the alphabet`

*Does this mean that she wants the alphabet to be in all capitals?*

Comment: `char[] upperAlpha = new char[]{'A', 'B', .... , 'Z'}`

Comment: Initializing an array means populating it with elements during the assignment. Uppercase letters of the alphabet are A,B,C,D,E,F.... Boris The Spider shows the way to do it with a char type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it just refers to all characters are all capitals.
No programming meaning.

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer. Answers don't start with "I think".

Answer (score 1):

> reading the data from a one-dimensional array that is initialized with the upper case letters of the alphabet

This means the array you're going to be working with is already constructed/created with all the letters in uppercase.

in other words as suggested in the comments:

```
char[] chars = new char[]{'A', 'B', .... , 'Z'}
```

Comment: Just a thought (and I know I wrote the comment) but it might be neater to init the array by creating one of the correct size then looping and setting values to `(char)(i + 65)`. Less typing... You could even be fancy and do it with a `Stream` - although you wouldn't get a `char[]` then.

Comment: @BoristheSpider definitely agreed, I wasn't actually expecting the OP to type every single character in the array by hand but rather "this is how your array would look like" prior to doing whatever your assignment criteria states. once again I definitely agree with you ;-).

Comment: @BoristheSpider or  they could box it to a `Character[]` if they want to proceed with the stream approach.

Comment: yeah - that's of course an option. I generally have somewhat of an aversion of `Character` though - it's like using a [tonne bag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_intermediate_bulk_container) to carry a pea around.

Comment: its old but... `(char)(i + 'A')` would be better (than `+ 65`, IMO)... alternative `"ABCDEF... Z".split("")` (more typing, less thinking ?)